# How to keep web.py app running always?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am running web py like below from terminal.

```
$ python app.py 8080
```

now how do i keep it running even when I close the terminal?
Is there any way to keep this server running.
Thank you

Comment: `nohup`, `screen`, `init.d` script, lots of options.  `nohup` is probably simplest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use **nohup** for that.

```
$ nohup python app.py 8080 &
```

It will stay open even if you close the terminal. You'll need to use kill and send some signal to it to close it.

Comment: seems like an overkill for what you asked, but use what you want, by all means

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a question belonging to another stackexchange site (serverfault?).

Anyway, the answer is: run it in a screen:

`screen python app.py 8080`

Detach from the screen using the key combination:

`Ctrl+a+d`

Attach to the screen again (to see ouput from your process)

`screen -r`

Quit screen:

`Ctrl+c`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). It is intended to do such tasks (and much more). Documentation is pretty clear, so it should not be a problem to set up it. See [how to run supervisord](http://supervisord.org/running.html).

Also do not use `nohup` since it will not do anything like autorestarting server after failure or after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In a Bourne-shell compatible shell (Bash, Bourne, Korn):

```
python app.py 8080 &
```

I just see that you wrote that you want to close the terminal. Apparently my answer won't work then.